# Maven Parent Pom with custom site.xml and images

Tags: maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I'm currently struggling with the maven site plugin. I have a corporporate/ super pom (packaging type pom) which defines all dependency version and also configures the site plugin. In addition I placed some image resources under /src/site/resources/images which are referenced in a custom site.xml (for example ./images/logo.jpg).

Another module references this parent pom and when I call mvn site it seems that the site.xml is getting picked up. But unfortunately the links to the images do not work. When I had a look in the target/site folder the images were missing. I also tried to create an additional 'corporate' resource module where I put the site resources (also under /src/site/resources), and reference this module as a dependency in the maven-site-plugin like this:

```xml
<build><plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-site-plugin.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.il</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${build-tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <reportPlugins>
            <plugin>
            ....
```

But this does not seem to work either. It worked for other reporting modules like pmd with special configurations which were placed under /src/main/resources though...the site resources does not seemed to be picked up and published to the repository.

So the question is: How is it possible to attach images and stylesheets to a maven super pom? I'm using Maven 3 btw...